# How to style a checkbox in a Visualforce page using Lightning Design System?

Tags: visualforce, lightning-design-system, inputcheckboxes, checkbox

Preferably without using JavaScript.

This is my code using the SLDS, but the field value doesn't change or get set.

```
<div class="slds-form-element">
    <div class="slds-form-element__control">
        <span class="slds-checkbox">
            <apex:inputCheckbox html-name="options" id="divsup" html-checked="{!myobject.field__c}" value="{!myobject.field__c}"></apex:inputCheckbox>
            <label class="slds-checkbox__label" for="divsup">
                <span class="slds-checkbox--faux"></span>
                <span class="slds-form-element__label">Checkbox Label</span>
            </label>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Has anyone been able to style the checkbox correctly?

In this case I was trying to rerender a `outputPanel` when the checkbox changes, but I didn't post the actionsupport used (because I noticed that the checkbox wasn't even clickable anymore).

I want to be able to style a checkbox, and listen for changes so I can rerender a panel.

Comment: does an outer element have the scope class?

Comment: Outer elements have "slds", "slds-grid", "slds-col" tags, and other slds align classes too. The whole page is styled, actually.

Comment: do you have another css on the page that could be overriding it? I just copied your code and it looks like it should.

Comment: No, the page is using just the SLDS. Have you tried using a rerender on the checkbox?

Comment: I did not, as there is no mention of `rerender` being part of the problem.

Comment: I noticed you are using `slds` as your scope class. So you are getting your SLDS from a static resource? Have you tried using the new `<apex:slds/>` to import your css? Maybe try that and change your scoping class to `slds-scope`

Comment: @Jesse, that's what I'm using. The new tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes you have to change the SLDS example to work correctly with Visualforce.

Visualforce depends on the input field having a specific "id" attribute, so the id of the checkbox is actually something like "j_id0:j_id2:divsup". This means the <label> element used by SLDS doesn't match your checkbox.

You have to use <apex:outputLabel> so Visualforce can match the ids of the label and the checkbox.

```
<div class="slds-form-element">
    <div class="slds-form-element__control">
        <span class="slds-checkbox">
            <apex:inputCheckbox html-name="options" id="divsup" html-checked="" value="{! isChecked}"></apex:inputCheckbox>
            <apex:outputLabel for="divsup" styleClass="slds-checkbox__label">
                <span class="slds-checkbox--faux"></span>
                <span class="slds-form-element__label">Checkbox Label</span>
            </apex:outputLabel>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Or if that doesn't work, you can fix-up these different ids when the page loads with this little bit of JavaScript.

```
var labels = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox'] + label");
for (var label of labels) {
    var checkbox = label.parentNode.querySelector("input");
    label.setAttribute("for", checkbox.id);
}
```